# "В Кремле оценили обмен задержанными между ..." - употребление "оценили"

Tags: стилистика, лексическая-сочетаемость

Почему-то режет глаз, когда слово **оценили** употребляют вместо "дали оценку", "прокомментировали".

Это уже стало общим местом в новостных заголовках, и пора бы привыкнуть, но в голове каждый раз звучит: "Хоботов, я всё оценила!"(с) "Покровские Ворота".

Вопрос - это нормативное употребление? Только меня оно раздражает?

Вот опять (газета.ру):

**"Онищенко оценил слова онколога о повышении смертности в России"**

*Бывший главный санитарный врач России Геннадий Онищенко не согласился с заявлением онколога о повышении риска смертности от рака из-за нехватки препаратов. Об этом сообщает информагентство Nation News*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из словаря:

ЦЕНИТЬ нсв. кого-что. 1. (св. оценить). Разг. Назначать, определять цену кому-, чему-л.; **оценивать**. Во что ты ценишь эту картину? 2. (св. оценить). **Судить** о ком-, чём-л., составлять мнение, суждение, **давать оценку**. Ц. людей по их заслугам.  3. Придавать особое значение кому-, чему-л.; **дорожить.** Ц. серьёзную музыку.

Что тут можно сказать? Словари словарями, а глагол ***ценить*** с позитивным значением,  который в словаре  **третий в списке** и вроде бы не имеет формы совершенного вида «оценить» на самом деле ее эту форму имел раньше и имеет сейчас, что видно из литературных текстов.

*Вы любви **не оценили**, милая Елена Ивановна, любви!* [Ф. М. Достоевский. Крокодил (1865)]

Я появился на сцене, шаркая ботинками и взмахивая руками. Так я изображал лыжника. Это была моя режиссерская находка, дань театральной условности. К сожалению, зрители **не оценили** моего формализма  [Сергей Довлатов. Чемодан (1986)]

*А слоны произвели впечатление… **мы с Машкой оценили**. Но это было единственным позитивным моментом. Представление Маше не понравилось.* [Андрей Клепаков. Опекун // «Волга», 2016]

Мы ясно видим **позитивную оценку** в значении глагола даже при отсутствии таких зависимых слов, как **высоко** оценили, **по достоинству** оценили.

Этот же глагол может иметь и негативное значение, но при этом  нужны зависимые слова:  *выступление оценили **как  неудачное,**  реформу оценили **как несвоевременную*.**

Но если мы говорим  ***оценили  поражение команды, оценил слова о повышении смертности,*** то это воспринимается как  несочетаемость понятий и **нарушение стиля**, что  и раздражает слух особо восприимчивых пользователей языка.

Мне такие сочетания тоже не нравятся, и я их оцениваю как **стилистическую ошибку.**

Comment: *"и я их оцениваю как стилистическую ошибку"* - и я тоже, но сделать с этим, по-видимому, ничего нельзя. Тем не менее - +1, и принял ответ.

Comment: Спасибо. Наверное, можно что-то сделать. Например, внести изменение в словарь, четко выделив позитивное значение, не требующее зависимых слов, а также значение "оценить каким-либо образом". Тогда к журналистам можно будет предъявить обоснованные претензии. Нас с вами править словари не пустят, но можно организовать общественное движение "Мы за правильный русский язык".

Comment: :)) Sharon, вы - идеалист. Нет, в принципе, если смотреть в далёкое будущее, нет ничего невозможного. У меня просто как-то не получается мыслить в этом ключе, но это - мои недостатки, видимо. Я читаю новостные заголовки ежедневно, и отдельные статьи тоже - волосы дыбом... уже не встают, привык. :) Вот это вот "оценить" - это такая мелочь по сравнению с остальными "перлами"...

Comment: Нам с вами нужно набрать всего-то 10 процентов сторонников, так что за дело... Цифра записана вот здесь https://www.gazeta.ru/science/2011/07/27_a_3709709.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Выражение "**дали оценку**" *отличается* от "**оценили**": "данная оценка" может быть абсолютно *любой* (от восторженной до убийственно-уничижительной). В политическом контексте, конечно, убедительнее было бы сказать "**оценили положительно**" (= как повод для оптимизма и т п.), что и встречается в других источниках по поводу того же события. Журналисты "газеты-ру" упростили выражение до слова "оценили", памятуя о типично положительном смысловом оттенке слова (ср. *оценить щедрость* и т. п.), забыв о контексте. Обычная для журналистов *стилистическая небрежность* - приходится на неё скидку делать, а речевой ошибки здесь нет.

Comment: О чём и речь. "Оценил/оценила" всё чаще употребляется "невпопад", что и сподвигло меня на вопрос. В заголовок вопроса пошла первая попавшаяся ссылка, но там же рядом: ["Кириленко оценил выступление сборной России на Кубке мира"](https://www.gazeta.ru/sport/news/2019/09/06/n_13431673.shtml) (текст: «Обидное поражение. Сборная могла выступить лучше. Хотя задача-минимум была выполнена») и т.д. Мне такие "нескладухи" бросаются в глаза по две штуки в день, не меньше.

Answer (score 0):

Нормативное.

У "оценить" есть значение "признать положительные качества", с которым "простая" оценка может перекрываться, но в словарях оно обычно идёт последним, в чём вы можете сами убедиться.

БТС Кузнецова:

> 2. чего. Определить качество, уровень чего-л., дать оценку чему-л. *О. работу, выступление. О. знания, способности. О. ответ студента. О.
>      книгу, спектакль, фильм.*

МАС:

> 2. Составить представление, суждение о ком-, чем-л., определить значение, характер, роль и т. п. кого-, чего-л. *--- мы оценим это
>      требование с точки зрения интересов пролетариата, приняв во внимание
>      все обстоятельства дела ---. Ленин, Ответ на критику нашего проекта
>      программы. Я представлял себя и ее в современной действительности и
>      старался взвесить и оценить наши отношения. Короленко, История моего
>      современника. Все по-разному и неправильно оценили его смущение.
>      Леонов, Взятие Великошумска.*

ТС Ожегова и Шведовой:

> 3. Высказать мнение, суждение о ценности или значении кого-чего-н. *О. чей-н. поступок. Правильно о. создавшееся положение.*

Там же:

> **оценка** 2. Мнение о ценности, уровне или значении кого-чего-н. *Дать оценку чему-н. Высокая о.*

Ушаков:

> 2. Высказать то или иное мнение, суждение о ценности кого-чего-н., понять правильно значение, качество кого-чего-н. *Он не узнает, не
>      оценит тоски твоей. Лермонтов. Оценить достоинства работника. Оценить
>      чьи-н. чувства. Оценить по достоинству (дать правильную оценку,
>      суждение о ком-чем-н.).*